# I've installed pillow and can't import it into the python shell

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-import, windows-10-desktop, python-3.9

I've looked over 30 different pages and couldn't find the answer I needed. I'm using a windows 10 and I'm using python 3.9.0. So I installed Pillow 8.1.0 like this:

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Then tried to import pillow into the shell using:

```
import PIL
import Pillow
import pillow
from Pillow import Image
from PIL import Image
from PIL import *
from Pillow import *
```

but I got the `ModuleNotFoundError` every time.

Do you have another way to put pillow into the python shell?

Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: `import PIL` or `from PIL import Image` are the correct imports.  Run `python3 -m pip list` and make sure it lists as installed.

Comment: The pillow [tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html) shows the proper way to `import` things. The pillow fork of the PIL is different in this respect, so you need to be aware of that especially when using code written for the original library. This is mentioned in this [warning](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=import#warnings).

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, try this:

in your python terminal run:

```
import sys
print(f'"{sys.executable}" -m pip install pillow')
print(f'"{sys.executable}" -m pip install requests')
```

then, with the printouts you get, run your windows command prompt as an admin (right click -> run as admin) then paste the 2 commands you get back. restart python and you SHOULD be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

With python 3.9 and above using Pillow 8.1.0, use
from pil import Image.

Comment: You're close. `from PIL import Image` (remember, it's case sensitive)